# Why does FindInstance fail when Solve succeeds on these simple constraints?

Tags: equation-solving

Why does

```
FindInstance[{a, b} > 0.27 && a == 10^8 && b == 2, {a, b}]
```

fail even though

```
Solve[{a, b} > 0.27 && a == 10^8 && b == 2, {a, b}]
```

works fine?

How do I make it succeed in such scenarios (when I only want one of potentially many roots)?

Comment: @Artes: My previous question is actually unrelated to this issue, hence why I asked a separate question. Yes I am sure the system interprets this correctly; the same behavior holds for `FindInstance[a > 0.27 && b > 0.27 && a == 10^8 && b == 2, {a, b}]`. Did you try running it? Also, what do you mean what is my problem? My problem is that `FindInstance` doesn't find the obvious solution, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Try e.g. `FindInstance[a > 27/100 && b > 27/100 && a == 10^8 && b == 2, {a, b}]`. Then decide how to formulate the problem.

Comment: @Artes: I can't really pick and choose what equations the user gives me when I'm using this as a subroutine... also, see my comment on the answer below.

Comment: My first though `{a, b} > .27` is not a valid inequality (It is never true).  Somewhat puzzled why `Solve` works though.

Comment: @george2079 from the way it is treated, I take it `>` is listable

Comment: @george2079: It's a vector inequality, pretty standard notation in math and in Mathematica.

Comment: If `Greater` were listable , `{1,1}>0` would give us `{True,True}`. Anyway I see that it works but it seems oddly undocumented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution myself: call `Reduce[]` on the input of `FindInstance[]`:

```
FindInstance[Reduce[{a, b} > 0.27 && a == 10^8 && b == 2, {a, b}], {a, b}]
```

I'm guessing it's a bug; if someone can figure out *why* this is happening, I'd still like to know.

Answer (score 7):

I can't find in the documentation that the input expressions need to be exact numbers, but if you look at all the examples of [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html), you see they all use rational numbers.  So rationalize your expression and it works,

```
FindInstance[Rationalize[{a, b} > 0.27 && a == 10^8 && b == 2], {a, b}]
(* {{a -> 100000000, b -> 2}} *)
```

There is some bug going on here, you can see that for some values `FindInstance` returns an answer, while for others it does not,

```
{wk, nwk} = 
 Reap[Do[If[
     Length@FindInstance[a == 10^8 && b == 2 && {a, b} > n, {a, b}] < 
      1, Sow[n, tag1], Sow[n, tag2]], {n, 0, 1, .01}]][[2]]
(* {{0., 0.03, 0.05, 0.06, 0.08, 0.09, 0.11, 0.14, 0.16, 0.17, 
  0.19, 0.2, 0.22, 0.25, 0.28, 0.3, 0.31, 0.33, 0.34, 0.36, 0.39, 
  0.41, 0.42, 0.44, 0.45, 0.47, 0.5, 0.53, 0.55, 0.56, 0.58, 0.59, 
  0.61, 0.64, 0.66, 0.67, 0.69, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75, 0.78, 0.8, 0.81, 
  0.83, 0.84, 0.86, 0.89, 0.91, 0.92, 0.94, 0.95, 0.97, 1.}, {0.01, 
  0.02, 0.04, 0.07, 0.1, 0.12, 0.13, 0.15, 0.18, 0.21, 0.23, 0.24, 
  0.26, 0.27, 0.29, 0.32, 0.35, 0.37, 0.38, 0.4, 0.43, 0.46, 0.48, 
  0.49, 0.51, 0.52, 0.54, 0.57, 0.6, 0.62, 0.63, 0.65, 0.68, 0.71, 
  0.73, 0.74, 0.76, 0.77, 0.79, 0.82, 0.85, 0.87, 0.88, 0.9, 0.93, 
  0.96, 0.98, 0.99}} *)
```

There is an error message which isn't reported,

```
Trace[
 FindInstance[{a, b} > 0.27 && a == 10^8 && b == 2, {a, b}], 
 Message[___]]
(* {{Message[FindInstance::lpsnf], Message[Message::msgl,$MessageList]}}} *)
```

As far as I can [tell](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Simplex/lpsnf.html), this message simply means no solution can be found,

[image]

Comment: I guess this works (+1) but it's more of a workaround rather than an explanation or solution.

Comment: Especially, note that the documentation says, *`FindInstance` gives results in the same form as `Solve` if an instance exists, and if it does not*... which means it has to return a solution if and only if `Solve` would find a solution.

Comment: @Mehrdad  This seems to be a bug of some kind, but a really minor one.  Is there a more complex example where this happens to you?  If you can find out what the error message `FindInstance::lpsnf` means then you may find out what is happening here

Comment: My example was actually way more complicated than this... I spent 15 minutes simplifying it, because in my experience when I don't do that then people vote me down and tell me to simplify it to a minimum bare-bones example. =P I'm also not sure where you saw the error (I didn't see it?) but it doesn't really explain what is going on either.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this will help someone understand the problem:

```
FindInstance[a > 0.1 && a == 2^24 - 1, {a}]
```

> {{a -> 1.67772*10^7}}

```
FindInstance[a > 0.1 && a == 2^24, {a}]
```

> {}

Obviously the real inequality is forcing the whole analysis to be real, but something seems to be single precision under the hood.

Giving "any" precision to the real value fixes things:

```
FindInstance[a > .1`16 && a == 2^24, {a}]
```

> {{a -> 1.67772160000000*10^7}}

Comment: +1 it did not occur to me this was a single-precision-ness issue, thanks for that!